# Using Javascript Regex For Removing Chars in String

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function that will validate a string for improper chars.

As a first try, i tried it on numbers. It Works on IE9,  but not on Chrome 12.0.742.122 and Firefox 5 & 6

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Regex Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var regexp;
            var input;
            var output;

            function replaceChars()
            {
                regexp = "";
                output = "";
                input = document.getElementById("myinput").getAttribute("value");
                regexp = /\d+/g;
                output = input.replace(regexp, "");//Remove Digits
                setOutput();
            }

            function setOutput()
            {
                document.getElementById("myoutput").setAttribute("value", output);
                document.getElementById("myexpr").setAttribute("value", regexp);
                document.getElementById("myinput").select();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        Enter : <input type="text" id="myinput" value="" maxlength="25" size="25"/><br/>
        RegEx : <input type="text" id="myexpr" value="" maxlength="25" size="25" readonly /><br/>
        Output : <input type="text" id="myoutput" value="" maxlength="25" size="25" readonly />
        <input type="button" #nClick="replaceChars();" value="Remove Digits"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 regexp = /\w+/g; remove character
regexp = /\w+/i;  remove all character lower case and uppercase
regexp = /\D+/i;  remove Non digits u can use any thing u wish...
output = input.replace(regexp, "");//Remove Digits
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is `onclick` and not `#nClick`.

Also, instead of `getAttribute`/`setAttribute`, you can set attributes directly like this:

```
input = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
```

and

```
document.getElementById("myoutput").value = output;
```

Then it works fine on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/Ta6Lw/.

Answer (score 0):

and also u used

```
onClick instead of #nClick
<input type="button" #nClick="replaceChars();" value="Remove Digits"/>
```